# How to handle push notifications from Parse in Ionic (Cordova/PhoneGap)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am developing an android application with **Ionic framework** (which works with Cordova and PhoneGap). I can receive already push notifications from Parse in a device but I do not know how can I handle them,I have searched and I have not found any concrete answers on how to implement a specific handler for Parse notifications.

For receiving push notifications I make use of this plugin: https://github.com/cranberrygame/cordova-plugin-pushnotification-parse.

I would like to handle them without having to change anything from the Android build, just with the javascript code from the framework.

Is it posible? How would it be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone comes here, I did not find any solution so I just used native Android java code to manage notifications.

Comment: I was very happy with the [FrostyElk/cordova-parse-plugin](https://github.com/FrostyElk/cordova-parse-plugin). It sends the push data to the javascript. I have forked the project and made some fixes that allows it to run with Cordova 5. My fork is here: [mobiRic/cordova-parse-pushhandler](https://github.com/mobiRic/cordova-parse-pushhandler)

Comment: I will check it and try but I see no documentation. Anyway I think with the .js file I can manage. Thank you!